# Excel: Count the number of matches between lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I have two lists, each on separate tabs. One list occupies B5:B10 (though the number of rows could change) and the other is named "proteins". I want to count the number of matches between the lists (if it matters, the first list is shorter). I tried `=COUNTIF(proteins,B5:B10)` and `=COUNTIF(B5:B10,proteins)`. Am I even on the right track?

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired outputs, your question isn't clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B5:B10,proteins))
```